# What is a better way to implement this if else logic?

Tags: java

I have a problem with getting my logic to work or better still I need a better way to implement this if-else situation.

I have 3 different conditions that set different properties and I want data to be persisted to database only when all conditions evaluate to true and not persist when any or all of the different conditions evaluate to false.

```
if (a>b){
  em.setAlpha();
}else{
  //throw error that prevents em.persist
}

if (c>d){
  em.setBeta();
}else{
  //throw error that prevents em.persist
}

if (e>f){
  em.setOmega();
}else{
  //throw error that prevents em.persist
}

//Should persist only when all conditions evaluate to true and not 
//persist when one or more of the conditions evaluates to false(throws an error)
database.persist(em);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a boolean flag:

```
boolean persist = true;

if (a>b){
  em.setAlpha();
}else{
  persist = false;
}

if (c>d){
  em.setBeta();
}else{
  persist = false;
}

if (e>f){
  em.setOmega();
}else{
  persist = false;
}

if (persist) {
  database.persist(em);
}
```

Comment: While this solution works, the OP was asking for a way to implement the entirety of his if-else logic.  This answer still uses the same method.

Comment: Not really, he asked for a way to know that the three of the if-statements are true, a flag works just right.

I prefer your answer phantom because its shorter but maybe he may need a representation of the evaluation to persist and be used elsewhere, in which i prefer Ozans answer, he can send that flag to any method that may use something like "aMethodThatUsesTheFlag(boolean persist)".

But since that is not in the scope i would accept phantom's answer

Comment: correct answer.
Can be shortened by embedding `persist` assignment into the condition: `if(persist &= a > b)`
This way, `else` can be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

You would be far better using the [and operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html):

Note: I'm not entirely sure from the context what your setAlpha functions are, so this *may* not work.  If you clarify this in your original question I will fix it here.

```
if (a > b && c > d && e > f) {
    em.setAlpha();
    em.setBeta();
    em.setOmega();
    database.persist(em);
}
else {
    // We show up here if one of the conditions was false.
}
```

Hope this helped.  Good luck!

Comment: what happened to `setAlpha() / ...` ?

Comment: @jp-jee Whoops.  Yes true, I'll add those.

Comment: @luisdurazoa I'm sorry what date?

Comment: Now the answer is wrong. :-/ The original logic doesn't require all conditions to be true just to set, say, alpha. (Other answer makes the same mistake.)

Comment: @phantom Now you've changed the logic. Calling the `setXXX()` does not depend on _all_ the comparison results

Comment: Yeah I realize that after @jp-jee pointed that out.  Sorry folks.

Answer (score 1):

If the processing order is fixed, you could use OOP design pattern "Chain Of Responsibility" for this problem. Here is a small program I put together as an illustration:

```
class JavaObj  {
    public void setAlpha() {}
    public void setBeta() {}
    public void setOmega() {};
}
class DB  {
    public void persist(JavaObj obj) {}
}
abstract class Handler {
    protected Handler successor;
    public void setSuccessor(Handler successor){
        this.successor = successor;
    }
    abstract public boolean processRequest(Integer [] params, JavaObj request);
}
class AlphaHandler extends Handler {
    public AlphaHandler (Handler successor) { setSuccessor(successor); }
    public boolean processRequest(Integer [] params, JavaObj request) {
        if (params[0]>params[1]) {
            request.setAlpha();
            return (successor==null) ? true : successor.processRequest(params, request);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
class BetaHandler extends Handler {
    public BetaHandler (Handler successor) { setSuccessor(successor); }
    public boolean processRequest(Integer [] params, JavaObj request) {
        if (params[2]>params[3]) {
            request.setBeta();
            return (successor==null) ? true : successor.processRequest(params, request);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
class OmegaHandler extends Handler {
    public OmegaHandler (Handler successor) { setSuccessor(successor); }
    public boolean processRequest(Integer [] params, JavaObj request) {
        if (params[4]>params[5]) {
            request.setOmega();
            return (successor==null) ? true : successor.processRequest(params, request);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
public class ChainOfResponsibilityAsExample {
    // setup the chain of responsibilities 
    private static Handler omegaHandler = new OmegaHandler(null);
    private static Handler betaHandler = new BetaHandler(omegaHandler);
    private static Handler processor = new AlphaHandler(betaHandler);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         DB database = new DB();
         JavaObj em = new JavaObj();
         Integer[] intArray = new Integer[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

         if (processor.processRequest(intArray, em)) {
             database.persist(em);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: This made me understand how chain of responsibility works way way better.. I'll try this out so I better understand this OOP design pattern

Comment: This seems heavy for the question under consideration.

Comment: You set up the "chain of responsibility" chain once, the processing is cleaver

Answer (score -1):

You could do this, using and to shorten your code:

```
// We set the valid ones
if (a > b) {
    em.setAlpha();
} else {
    //throw error that prevents em.persist
}
if (c > d) {
    em.setBeta();
} else {
    //throw error that prevents em.persist
}
if (e > f) {
    em.setOmega();
} else {
    //throw error that prevents em.persist
}

public boolean validate() {
    if ((a > b) && (c > d) && (e > f)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

if (validate()) {
    database.persist(em);
}
```

After that you can call `if validate()` to check conditions more quickly as well.

Comment: This doesn't capture the logic in the original question.

Comment: Wouldn't it? By calling `if validate() { database.persist(em); }`

Comment: Naw, because the original code doesn't require every condition to be true just to set, say, alpha.

Comment: You are right, that was my mistake. I was misled by the quote _and I want data to be persisted to database only when all conditions evaluate to true_ and missed the underlying logic.

Comment: It's not my downvote, but one suggestion would be to move the setXXX() methods up to the top like in the original question. No reason to duplicate all that setXXX() stuff in the "all true" condition. Then at the end just return (a>b && c>d && e>f).

Comment: Good call, made that edit, it does make the code shorter